# Any way to use Help.ShowHelp in Windows CE Core license build?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I am developing a Compact Framework 3.5 application for Windows CE 6.0.  Help.ShowHelp() throws a NotSupportedException.  At windowsembedded.com I found this statement:

"Help is not included in the Core run-time because it requires a browser."

Is this the reason for the exception?  If so, is there any recommended way to get around this issue or do I need to build my own help system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowHelp uses the browser control (via webview.dll IIRC) under CE.  The browser control is definitely part of the Professional CE license SKU (assessment tool [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4fb630a8-b710-4b50-bbd0-52a51fdae6e8&displaylang=en).  There used to be a Word doc that listed every component, but I can't seem to locate a download for it), so you will have to roll your own Help framework if you intend to stay with a Core license.  Options might be to use [Opera](http://www.opera.com/pressreleases/en/2006/10/03/) or [MiniMo](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Minimo:WinCe/Device_Matrix) as a browser, but you'd still have to roll all of the searh/help stuff.

Using RTF might be simpler.